# Как соединять однотипные объекты при перетаскивании, и создавать новый объект?

Tags: android, c#, android-studio, unity3d

Пожалуйста помогите реализовать: соединение однотипных объектов при перетаскивании, и создавать новый объект, чтоб вам было наглядно понятно как это должно работать, скину ссылку на игру где есть то что мне надо [Эволюция Человека Кликер: Игра про Жизнь](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.banana4apps.evolution) очень интересно посмотреть на такой скрипт, заранее огромное спасибо :)

Comment: Играл в нее и тоже задавался таким вопросом. Можно навесить на каждый колайдер, и при пересечении проверку делать, если тот кто столкнулся = тот к кому косались, соединить.

Comment: Если так сделать то при обычном передвижение они тоже будут соединяться, но мне надо именно когда ты перетаскиваешь ! Слушай может поможешь как нибудь пожалуйста ?

Comment: А если в момент нажатия булеву переменную на `true` ставить, и когда соединять, то и переменную учитывать

Comment: Какая личная помощь нужна будет, у меня в профиле ссылки (пиши только в случае не соответствия тематики сайта тут)

Comment: Хорошо буду знать к кому обращаться за помощью )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я считаю ответ @Andrey единственно правильным, но немного детальнее распишу.

1. Вы создаете скрипт на `Drag And Drop` под Unity.
2. Рисуешь схему всех возможных "спариваний" на бумаге
3. создаешь под каждый возможный вид обьекта свой класс, который наследуется от BaseAnimal (который является драг енд дропом)
4. В функции драг енд дропа пытаешься понять какого же именно вида Animal был закинут и

   4.1. Сначала создаешь новый Animal с координатами того, на которого дропали

   4.2. а потом дестроишь оба объекта

   4.3 на месте перетаскивания объекта пускаешь анимацию дымка которая будет по размерам БОЛЬШЕ любого из объектов Animal. (скрытие момента исчезновения двух тварей и появления третей)

Именно в такой последовательности.

ну и, собственно, все.

Ну и можно усложнить логику и добавить вариативность. Типа при соединении 2х тварей ты с вероятностью в 30% создаешь тварь 3 и с вероятностью в 70 - тварь 4. Но как по мне, то это слишком сложно и излишество.

PS: Кстати, уверяю что именно по такой логике была реализована Materia Fusion в Final Fantasy Crisis Core и во многих других играх :) Проверяется просто: можно найти в интернете точный список что конкретно нужно объединить что бы получить конкретный результат.

PS2: Для упрощения структуры спаривания ты можешь создать логику на основе неких интерфейсов. То есть, например у тебя есть 3 твари которые наследуются от интерфейса `IBeast1` и 3 твари которые наследуются от `IBeast2`. И их объединение даст один конкретный результат — `IBeastN`. При чем случайным из 3х представителей IBeastN :)

Comment: Перетаскивать объект я могу, не можешь дальше помочь пожалуйста в свободное время ?! если надо скрипт на движение мой могу скинуть.

Comment: не, ищи конкретно скрипт реализации драг-енд-дроп-а, я немного смотрел что есть в интернете и видел парочку, но не проверял их работу, само собою. А на перетаскивание обьектов по сцене вообще есть стандартный скрипт в юнити, так что если ты его писал сам -- то это была лишняя работа :)

Comment: Делать рандомный результат в таких играх - такой себе геймдизайн конечно :)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, вам нужно заранее знать комбинации и что они дают. 
Как вариант вам нужны классы каждого типа. Там бактерия, человек и прочее в таком же духе.  Стоит обзавестись базовым классом для всех с методом объединения. В метод передавать с кем вы обьеденяете. А в каждом классе иметь свой список ключ значения. Входной тип и результат слияния. 
И так с каждым. Да, много работы, но в любом случае нужно заранее знать результаты слияний. 
Пока что это мой вариант придуманный на ходу. Если вам он покажется интересным то можем обговорить детали и как то его улучшить.

Comment: Такой вариант очень даже интересный!
Где и когда можно обсудить это всё ?)

Comment: У меня в профиле мой скайп.  Можете написать туда. попробуем решить эту проблему в переписке там

Comment: Вот Андрей, я вот делаю вашу задумку *(до того как вы написали)* я туплю на моменте результата слияния. У меня из пары не 1 выходит а тоже пара. Что скажете?

Comment: я так понимаю в вашем варианте тоже есть общий для всех классов  метод слияния который переопределяется в каждом наследнике. да ?

Comment: расскажите подробнее о проблеме. Как именно у вас происходит слияние, В общих словах ваш алгоритм. если можно

Comment: Я даже не понимаю как подойти к этому. У меня на этапе удаление обоих `GameObject`

Comment: Тот алгоритм что я описывал он далеко неидеален.  Я написал его сразу же как увидел вопрос. Если над ним посидеть то можно придумать что то лучше. Но как я себе это вижу. Мы взяли какой то объект и переносим его на другой. Нам нужно в булевой переменной указать что этот объект не создаст другой. а служит только оплодотворителем что ли. Первое что пришло на ум.Это нам нужно что бы как раз не создались два объекта из каждого из родителей. Таким образом мы запретим тому что мы переносим создавать  новый объект. А тот на который мы переносим спокойно создаст новый

Comment: я бы сказал бы что это единственный вариант. Только можно еще добавить вариативность (то есть при обьединении 2х обьектов конкретного типа ты получаешь с вероятностью в 30 третий тип, а с вероятностью в 70% 4й тип). Но это уже лишнее усложнение. Еще советую начать вообще с рисования графика "спаривания" обьектов банально на бумаге :)